# How to load XML file in UFT from QC?

Tags: xml, qtp, alm

I'm trying to load(xmldoc.load) an XML config file from ALM/QC test resources and it's returning false, therefore no nodes can be selected.

Kindly assist. Thanx

Here is a sample of the the code below :

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xmlDoc.Async = False 
xmlDoc.Load("[ALM\Resources] Resources\Test_Resources\config")

Environment.LoadFromFile "[ALM\Resources] Resources\Test_Resources\Environment"

Set node_Environment = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/options/RunEnv/text()")

strEnvironment = node_Environment.NodeValue
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take your time to take the tour on how to create a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Once we have this sample, it will be much easier for users of the page to help you with your issue.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code? Can you load file from local path?

Comment: @ManishChristian, yes i have... The local file path works, the alm file path does not work. The local returns True, the alm returns False when i look at the code on the Watch list